# updating column in one dataframe with value from another dataframe based on matching values

Tags: r

I have a data frame "z"

```
   letter color
1       a     0
2       e     0
3       b     0
4       b     0
5       d     0
6       d     0
7       a     0
8       b     0
9       c     0
10      d     0
11      c     0
12      c     0
13      c     0
14      c     0
15      e     0
16      e     0
17      a     0
18      d     0
19      e     0
20      b     0
```

and another data frame "y"

```
  letter color
1      a   red
2      b  blue
3      c green
```

when the letter in z matches with a letter in y  I would like to append the color from y into the corresponding color field in z but I do not want to remove any values from z.  If a match doesn't occur, z$color should remain unchanged. I used"0" as a place holder in z$color, this could be text instead.

I've been attempting things for loops, the match() command and statements with %in% but I'm not quite achieving the results I'm after.

Any ideas?

This is the code I used for the data frames

```
set.seed(3)
z=data.frame(sample(c("a","b","c","d","e"),20,replace=T))
names(z)="letter"
z$color=rep(0,dim(z)[1])
z

y1=c("a","b","c")
y2=c("red","blue","green")
y=data.frame(cbind(y1,y2))
names(y)=c("letter","color")
y
```

Comment: With `match`, I guess it should be something like `y$color[match(z$letter, y$letter)]`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

you don't need `z$color` in the first place if its just place holder, you can replace `NA` later with `0`

```
z$color<-y[match(z$letter, y$letter),2]
```

Comment: I included the z$color because I was once told that it isn't efficient for R to populate an empty vector.  Basically define a vector for the output up front.  I can drop it no problem.  This toy example will eventually be expanded to a much larger data frame.  Your response was very helpful.  Very close to what I've been attempting for the last few hours but never hit on.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `merge`:

```
dat <- merge(z, y, by = "letter", all.x = TRUE)
transform(dat, color = ifelse(is.na(color.y), 
                              color.x, as.character(color.y)))[-(2:3)]

   letter color
1       a   red
2       a   red
3       a   red
4       b  blue
5       b  blue
6       b  blue
7       b  blue
8       c green
9       c green
10      c green
11      c green
12      c green
13      d     0
14      d     0
15      d     0
16      d     0
17      e     0
18      e     0
19      e     0
20      e     0
```

Comment: @WillPhillips No, the `NA`s are replaced by `replace`. The function `transform` is used to add a new column to the data frame.

Answer (score 4):

sqldf/sqlite is very flexible:

```
library(sqldf)
z$color="0" # to avoid conflicts numeric/characters
z <- sqldf(c("UPDATE z
             SET color = (SELECT y.color
                          FROM y
                          WHERE z.letter = y.letter
                           )
             WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM y
                           WHERE z.letter = y.letter
                           )"
             , "select * from main.z"
                  )
           )
z
   letter color
1       b  blue
2       a   red
3       d   0.0
4       d   0.0
5       e   0.0
6       a   red
7       a   red
8       c green
9       b  blue
10      c green
11      e   0.0
12      c green
13      b  blue
14      d   0.0
15      d   0.0
16      d   0.0
17      c green
18      e   0.0
19      a   red
20      c green
```