# Populate a column in one data frame based on matching values from another data frame

Tags: r

I and new R user and wonder if you might be able to help.

I have two data frames `ds` and `scotland`. ds contains a list of the first two characters of postcodes and I want to find out which of these are postcodes in Scotland. scotland contains a list of the first two characters of Scottish postcodes.

e.g.

ds

```
     areaid nation
1      CO     NA
2      NE     NA
3      SA     NA
4      PR     NA
5      SK     NA
6      CF     NA
7      CM     NA
8      RG     NA
9      OX     NA
10     HG     NA
11     RM     NA
12     YO     NA
13     WR     NA
14   <NA>     NA
15      S     NA
16     BD     NA
17     TA     NA
18     SE     NA
19     SO     NA
20   <NA>     NA
21     ME     NA
22     LL     NA
23     DD     NA
24     KY     NA
25     BB     NA
26     BB     NA
27     SN     NA
28      M     NA
29     RH     NA
30     EX     NA
```

and scotland:

```
     Country areaid
1  Scotland     AB
2  Scotland     CA
3  Scotland     DD
4  Scotland     DG
5  Scotland     EH
6  Scotland     FK
7  Scotland      G
8  Scotland     HS
9  Scotland     IV
10 Scotland     KA
11 Scotland     KW
12 Scotland     KY
13 Scotland     ML
14 Scotland     PA
15 Scotland     PH
16 Scotland     TD
17 Scotland     ZE
```

What I'd like to do is to populate the nation column with `scotland` if the value in `areaid$ds` appears in  `areaid$scotland`

I tried the popular soloution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712384/updating-column-in-one-dataframe-with-value-from-another-dataframe-based-on-matc) but got an error message because the number of rows is different.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you checked `?merge` or `?match`.

Comment: Thank you - I had tried 'merge' but couldn't get it to work. The duplicate question that @nrussell directed to has sorted it though. I hadn't known what to look for. Thank you, both.

Comment: Try: library(dplyr);(want<-left_join(ds,scotland,by=c("areaid")))